# using declarations importing member type of partially specialized base class template

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Are `using` declarations that import definitions from a base class invalid when the base class is a partially specialized version of the class being declared?

Given the code:

```
template <typename T> class FullySpecializedBase;

template <> class FullySpecializedBase<void> {
        typedef int my_type;
};

template <typename T>
class FullySpecializedBase : FullySpecializedBase<void> {
        using typename FullySpecializedBase<void>::my_type;
        my_type i;
};

template <> class FullySpecializedBase<int>;

template <typename T, typename V> class PartiallySpecializedBase;

template <typename V> class PartiallySpecializedBase<void, V> {
    typedef V my_type;
};

template <typename T, typename V>
class PartiallySpecializedBase : PartiallySpecializedBase<void, V> {
    using typename PartiallySpecializedBase<void, V>::my_type;
    my_type i;
};

template <> class PartiallySpecializedBase<int, int>;

int main() { return 0; }
```

compiled with `-std=c++98 -pedantic -Wall` using various versions of GCC and Clang 3.4.2

`PartiallySpecializedBase` will not compile on versions of GCC < 4.7 (tested back to at least 4.1.2) due to `minimal.cpp:24: error: ‘my_type’ does not name a type`.  However I'm unable to find a bug report (or much of anything really) that specifically mentions this issue.  Is the code incorrect, or was this simply a long-standing gcc bug?

Comment: In early C++ versions `my_type i` could be interpreted as ill-formed, because the dependent name `my_type` was introduced not specifically as a type name into the scope of the derived class. This was a defect and fixed in later versions. Possibly GCC<4.7 implements the old defective version of the language.

Comment: (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#11)

Comment: Based on my cursory reading of the defect, wouldn't both using declarations of my_type be ill-formed under the original language?  Only the second fails to compile...

Comment: No. The first is not dependent. The compiler knows when it parses the template that `my_type` is a type and is `int`. Not so for the second one. It could be a non-type (which doesn't make much sense, because you asserted on the line before that it is a type.. that's why it was considered a defect). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords